How to bypass Captcha using python
I know there are many other questions regarding this issue but they seem...outdated (?) or at least, they do not work anymore. I tried multiple methods such as proxy rotators, custom proxy lists (which ideally I'd like to avoid), using tor sessions through python, but none of these methods led me anywhere else besides this error:
--more--

 <p class="text-center text-red-800">
                                As you were using this website, something about your browser or behaviour made us think you might be a bot.<br/>Solve the captcha below to continue browsing the site.
                        </p>

--more--

Basically I am using python to scrape a website that offers properties like rooms, apartments etc. But I made a lot of requests (and that's the goal of the script) and now Im met with the mentioned captcha response.
The important part of my code that makes the requests and the initialization of the session is the following:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import random


def init(url):
    global session
    global proxies
    session = requests.Session()
    proxies = [
        'http://35.185.196.38:3128',
        'https://35.185.196.38:3128',
        'http://202.86.138.18:8080',
        'https://202.86.138.18:8080',
        'https://20.206.106.192:80',
        'https://20.210.113.32:80',
        'https://20.206.106.192:8123',
        'https://89.43.31.134:3128',
        'https://88.198.212.91:3128',
        'http://213.217.30.69:3128',
        'https://213.217.30.69:3128',
        'https://204.109.59.194:3121',
        'https://20.111.54.16:8123',
        'https://195.154.184.80:8080',

    ]

    proxy = random.choice(proxies)
    print(f"Using proxy: {proxy}")


    
    user_agent = UserAgent()
    session.headers.update({'User-Agent': str(user_agent)})

    response = session.get('https://[website_url]/')
    assert response.status_code == 200

    response = session.get('https://[website_url]/cgi-bin/fl/js/verify')
    assert response.status_code == 200

    try:
        response = session.get(url, proxies={'http': proxy, 'https': proxy}, timeout=10)
        return response
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Request error: {e}")
        return None
    

def scrape_website(url):
    response = session.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(response.text) # Here is where I print the response which contains the captcha response.
        -- rest of the code --



Which website is that?

@BarrythePlatipus pararius

Can you try to add headers from the website itself rather than fake_useragent.
add all the headers mentioned in a network of the URL.
e.g.:
headers = {
   'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
   'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
   'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.9',
   'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
   'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
   'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}


tried but it results in captcha once again.

which security the website is using. e.g. Cloudflare, Imperva

its using cloudflare

try to use this library [cloudscraper] https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/ or try this https://pypi.org/project/cfscrape/

Circumvent the captcha with a cheap proxy, depending on how many pages you want to scrape. When I was scraping Yandex search results which was giving me captcha after second request I used ScraperAPI

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
